# React native, are there shell commands lines for generate screens/navigation/... files ?

Tags: react-native

From Symfony or Drupal, I used to use the shell for generate templates empty files (pages, entity, ...)

I'm a new react native developer, its really useful to have a console for generate some projects files.
I make several google search but I find nothing..

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can not do this for react native. What you can do is use an editor like WebStorm and add some codes snippets and custom live templates. There is a great tutorial [here.](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/using-and-creating-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thank you :) I'll see that !